# Contextual Actionbar with DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I've been trying to implement a contextual action bar along with a dialog fragment. 
Similar to the downloads widget in android.

[image]

I've tried to set `android:windowActionModeOverlay` to be true in the theme.

But it doesnt seem to work.  Is there any way I can achieve it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The downloads window that you have in your screenshot is actually an `Activity` using the `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog` theme which makes it look like a dialog.  To achieve the same look as the downloads window, your `Activity` need only use the same theme.

You can set this theme in your manifest like so:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

---

**Example implementation excluding string and drawable resources.**

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mceley.dialog.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.mceley.dialog.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        findViewById(R.id.context_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ExampleMode mode = new ExampleMode();
        startActionMode(mode);
    }

    public class ExampleMode implements ActionMode.Callback {

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

main_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/context_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/show_context_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main_menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

Result:

[image: Dialog Example App]

Comment: I did come across this when searching. I wanted to know if there was a way to do it without creating an activity for the fragment. Anyways.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think you can add ActionBar in DialogFragment.**

But We can Try that using Activity As Dialog.

I have tried this with [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and I have added `R.style.Sherlock___Theme_Dialog` as my Activity's theme but it looks like this:

[image] [image] [image]

**After doing Above thing i understud, we can't Add `ActionBar` in `Dialog` or `DialogFragment`.**